# how to underline the access key in an input button

Tags: html, underline, html-input

I have a button and I would like to underline the access key letter, `<u></u>` doesn't work, and `C&#818;` (C̲) changes the font, it should be verdana

```
    <input class="boton" type="button" value="C&#818;ancel" accesskey="C" onclick="cancel();"/>
```

In my css I put the font type:

```
input.boton{

font: bold 11px verdana !important;
color: #000;

 }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: And if you use css it doesnt work?

.boton{
      font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif !important;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no HTML entity you can apply that would render an underline. Inside a `value` attribute you cannot use other HTML tags, so you can't render an underline this way. Using a Unicode *combining low line* may result in differently rendered fonts, as you notice, since you're generating a new character which your primary font may have issues rendering.

Therefore the best solution may be to use a `button`, which allows arbitrary HTML content:

```
<button ...>C<u>a</u>ncel</button>
```