# How to underline a hotkey with Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I created a hotkey at my primefaces component. It works as it should.
It's "Ctrl + S" shortcut. It submits a form.
Now, I would like to suggest to a user that it shortcut exist by showing underlined letter in button label. It would be like "S̲ave" where the ̲ is a 'combine an underline with the previous character'.

The problem is that when I run code from below the "S" letter has a smaller font.

It looks like "S" letter would be font size = 14 and rest of text size = 17. I don't know why.

```
<p:commandButton 
    id="ConfirmButton" 
    value="S&#818;ave" 
    icon="fa fa-save"
    action="#{cc.attrs.Bean.updateAction}"
/>
```

Comment: And what if you do a `<h:outputText value="S&#818;ave"/> Same result?

Comment: Might be duplicate of [how to underline the access key in an input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840537/how-to-underline-the-access-key-in-an-input-button)

Comment: @Selaron: Don't think so since the answer there says you can't combine an underline while in fact, even in that question, it seems you can, just the font changes, so the question is the same, but the answer there is not fully correct or the best

Comment: @Kukeltje, it's the same result.

Comment: Then the problem is not PrimeFaces related... And what if you do a `S&#818;ave` directly in the page? If that shows the same problem it is not even JSF related (and this is debugging, root cause analysis, something developers should always do)

Comment: If I do `S&#818;ave` directly in the page I have the same situation. "S" letter has a smaller font.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses. I've found a solution. 
I am passing the value `<u>S</u>ave` from a backing bean and it is interpreted because I changed the escape attribute value on false.

```
<p:commandButton 
    id="ConfirmButton" 
    value="#{cc.attrs.Bean.value}" 
    escape="false"
    icon="fa fa-save"
    action="#{cc.attrs.Bean.updateAction}"
/>
```

Comment: So effectively it is duplicate... then there us no need to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `::first-letter` trick to increase the font size of the first letter

**Update:**

For specific, you can use `:nth-letter` in css

Comment: But that only works if it is the first character and that might be the case in the actual question but not always applicable.

Comment: try *:nth-letter*